# Use Struct as a Ptr/class? Need a fix .NET

Tags: .net, class, struct

I wrote a bunch of code and i would like to fix it the fastest way possible. I'll describe my problem in a easier way.

I have apples and oranges, they are both Point and in the list apples, oranges. I create a PictureBox and draw the apple/oranges on screen and move them around and update the Point via Tag.

The problem now is since its a struct the tag is a copy so the original elements in the list are not update. So, how do i update them? I consider using Point? But those seem to be readonly. So the only solution i can think of is

- Clear the list, iterate through all the controls then check the picturebox property to check if the image is a apple or orange then add it to a list

I really only thought of this solution typing this question, but my main question is, is there a better way? Is there some `List<Ptr<Point>>` class i can use so when i update the apples or oranges through the tag the element in the list will update as a class would?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your naming:

```
public class Ptr<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public Ptr(T value) { Value = value; }
}
```

You can then make your list a `List<Ptr<Point>>`.

**Edit**

Alternatively, the absolute easiest solution would be to recreate the `Point` structure as a class within your own namespace.

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

That's obviously the barebones implementation; if you need additional functionality you'll obviously need to implement that yourself. This will, however, give you a mutable `Point` class.

Comment: I havent tested but wouldnt i need to rewrite a lot of code? to use .Value and not access .X, .Y directly?

Answer (score 1):

You should make a class to contain your `Point`s.

Comment: I am kind of asking if theres a built in way instead of writing my own. (or if theres an alternative solution, i am trying to rewrite as little as possible, maybe i can inherit but i cant write/text code until 2hrs from now)

Answer (score 0):

If value semantics are not what you want, then you should be using `class` instead of `struct`. Is there any reason why you cannot convert your `struct`s to `class`es?

**Edit** Ignore the above, I didn't quite understand what was being asked, but I think SLaks has the correct solution.

Comment: He cannot change `System.Drawing.Point`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right... I think the question was edited after my answer cause I didn't quite understand what was being asked :)